# PHP/MySQL adding <li> before and </li> after every row

Tags: php, mysql

My db table is:

```
id  content
1   row1
    row2
    row3
2   id2row1
    id2row2
```

I'm trying to print (echo) content with splitting to lines,

I've tried nl2br but is displaying in this way:

```
row1<br />
row2<br />
row3<br />
```

What I'm trying to do is displaying in this way:

```
<li>row1</li>
<li>row2</li>
<li>row3</li>
```

Comment: So... what's your question?  If you want it to appear in `<li></li>` tags, then just add them to the string before you `echo` it.  P.S. `<li></li>`s can only exist as a child of a `<ul></ul>`.

Comment: Could we see the loop you're using to ```echo``` the query results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$values = explode(PHP_EOL, $row);
foreach($values AS $data){
    echo '<li>'.$data.'</li>';
}
```

You should normalize this data, it's not the right way to store it.

Answer (score 0):

Using regex, you could do this:

```
$content = <<<EOL
line 1
line 2
line3
EOL;

$parsed = "<li>".preg_replace('/(\r\n|\n)/',"</li>$1<li>",$content)."</li>";
echo $parsed;
```

Output:

```
<li>line 1</li>
<li>line 2</li>
<li>line3</li>
```

Comment: @Glavić Not that regex is ever easy to read, but boy is that an eye-full.